# How to change this script to autoscroll?

Tags: javascript, autoscroll

I have a script which has a button to scroll the site but I need it to scroll automatically on page load. I need the script to scroll exactly like shown below, except the button. Could anyone change it for me? I'm new to javascript, thanks..

```
function scroll(element, speed) {
    var distance = element.height();
    var duration = distance / speed;
    element.animate({scrollTop: distance}, duration, 'linear');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        scroll($("html, body"), 0.015); // Set as required
    });
});
```

Comment: remove $("button").click(function() {

Comment: thank you it works. now I look very stupid I guess..

Comment: No problem, we are learning. Cheers!

Comment: i noticed its not scrolling to the end of the page and stops somewhere in the middle. you know how to solve this?

Comment: Look inside scroll funct(), the first param is **$("html, body")** and the function calculate the height and scroll to the bottom of the element. So... put there an element to scroll to it.

Comment: what do you mean with "put there an element"? if I change it to an id like 'scrollto', it doesnt work. also stops in the middle and I tried with 'html' or 'body' too. is there a way to make the script scroll to a div with id?

Comment: Yes, the first param is the element limiter to scroll. Put there the id and it will scroll to that element.id, **example** scroll($("#your-element-id"), 0.015);

Answer (score 0):

Call the scroll function in on window load, this will scroll the page on load finished.

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
 scroll($("html, body"), 0.015); // Set as required
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below JavaScript code

```
var div = $('.autoscroller');

$('.autoscroller').bind('scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup', function(evt) {
    if (evt.type === 'DOMMouseScroll' || evt.type === 'keyup' || evt.type === 'mousewheel') {

    }
    if (evt.originalEvent.detail < 0 || (evt.originalEvent.wheelDelta && evt.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0)) { 
        clearInterval(autoscroller);
    }
    if (evt.originalEvent.detail > 0 || (evt.originalEvent.wheelDelta && evt.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0)) { 
        clearInterval(autoscroller);
    }
});

var autoscroller = setInterval(function(){
    var pos = div.scrollTop();
    if ((div.scrollTop() + div.innerHeight()) >= div[0].scrollHeight) {
        clearInterval(autoscroller);
    }
    div.scrollTop(pos + 1);
}, 50);
```

here on the load of the page. The text are auto-scrolled upto the end of the page.